# SQL takes very long to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server

This SQL statement left joins two tables, both with approx. 10.000 rows (table1 = 20 columns, table2 = 50+ columns), and it takes 60+ seconds to execute. Is there a way to make it faster?

```
SELECT 
    t.*, k.*
FROM 
    table1 AS t 
LEFT JOIN 
    table2 AS k ON t.key_Table1 = k.Key_Table2
WHERE 
    ((t.Time) = (SELECT MAX(t2.Time) FROM table1 AS t2 
                 WHERE t2.key2_Table1 = t.key2_Table1))
ORDER BY 
    t.Time;
```

The ideal execution time would be < 5 seconds, since Excel query does it in 8 secs, and it is very surprising that Excel query would work faster than a SQL Server Express query.

Execution plan:

[image]

Comment: You have to provide your execution plan

Comment: The ideal execution time is always zero seconds, you get as close to that as you can! You'll need to provide details of your tables' schema, indexes and the actual execution plan using [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan). Half your query execution time is spent sorting data, so indexes here will help.

Comment: Can you put it words what this sql is trying to accomplish?

Comment: The Query is trying to select the last "Key" value, depending on the "Time" of input. Therefore, if there are two inputs under the "Key" value, first at 10am, second at 11am, the query takes the latest, in this case the second, entered at 11am. At the moment we've sped up the query loading process by copying the Access DB to local disc and calling the query from there, which shaves the time from +120secs to approx. 5-11secs, depending on the VPN connection. We have also added the Indexes as it was suggested and it helped a lot. I am still open to upgrading the query efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

also you can rewrite your query better :

```
select *
from table2 as k
join (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by Key_Table2 order by time desc) rn 
    from table1
  ) t 
on t.rn = 1 
and t.key_Table1 = k.Key_Table2
```

but you need index on Key_Table2, time and key_Table1 columns if you already don't have.
also another improvement would be to select only columns you want instead of select *

Answer (score 1):

The optimizer is determining that a merge join is best, but if both tables have 10,000 rows and they aren't joining on indexed columns then forcing the optimizer to get out of the way and telling it to hash join may improve performance

The syntax would be to change LEFT JOIN to LEFT HASH JOIN

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms191426(v=sql.100)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-join?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although links might be valid answers, please provide a code snippet example as links might break over time. For more tips see [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend rewriting the query using `outer apply`:

```
SELECT t.*, k.*
FROM table1 t OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) k.*
      FROM table2 k 
      WHERE t.key_Table1 = k.Key_Table2
      ORDER BY Time DESC
     ) k
ORDER BY t.Time;
```

And for this query, you want an index on `table2(Key_Table2, time desc)`.